# Need help rewriting this in a DRY format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, dry

I am currently building an API application using Express and MongoDb.
I am very new to JavaScript. Any suggestions on writing this in a cleaner and DRYer way?

```
var firstName = req.query.firstName;
var students = req.query.students;
    if(firstName){
        Instructor.find({firstName: firstName},function(err,instructors){
          if(err) 
            res.status(500).send(err);
          else
          res.json(instructors);
        });
        console.log("Instructor name is ", req.query.firstName);
    }
    else if(students){
        Instructor.find({students: students},function(err,instructors){
          if(err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
          else
          res.json(instructors);
        });
    }
    else{
        Instructor.find(function(err,instructors){
          if(err) 
            res.status(500).send(err);
          else
          res.json(instructors);
        });
    }
```

Comment: If this is working code, this question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that seems to be different in the `if` blocks is the first parameter (if any) that you pass to the `Instructor.find`.

You could use the `if` statements only to determine the first parameter and call `Instructor.find` only once with the appropriate parameters.

Here is an example:

```
var firstName = req.query.firstName;
var students = req.query.students;
var params = [];
var callback = function(err,instructors){
    if(err) 
      res.status(500).send(err);
    else
      res.json(instructors);
  };

if(firstName){
    params.push({firstName: firstName});
} else if(students){
    params.push({students: students});
}

params.push(callback);
Instructor.find.apply(Instructor, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the part that executes the query and the query response handler seems to be the same. The conditional part is the query construction.

```
var firstName = req.query.firstName;
var students = req.query.students;

var query = {};
if (firstName) {
    req.query.firstName = firstName;
} else if (students) {
    req.query.students = students;
} else {
    return next(new Error('Invalid request'));
}

Instructor.find(query, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        // You should sanitize this error though
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    return res.json(results);
});
```

Now, in practice, you should consider validating the query parameters a bit more. e.g: `_.isArray(req.query.students) && !_.isEmpty(req.query.students)`. Then, the array of students can contain duplicate keys. e.g: `[1,1,1,1,1,1....` (1000 times). This can be used as a denial of service. Try to do `_.uniq` on arrays of ids before using them.

For strings... `_.isString(req.query.firstName) && _.isEmpty(req.query.firstName)`.

In those cases, return HTTP 400.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you mind explaining a bit more about how to write the code? :)